# Can such a Turing-recognizable language exist?

Tags: turing-machines

Suppose $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$. Is the following claim correct?

> There exists a Turing-recognizable language $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ such as its complement is not Turing-recognizable, and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it contains exactly $n$ strings of length $n$.

I'm kind of lost here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried proving there is no such language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $L$ is a recognizable language that contains $f(n)$ strings of length $n$, where $f$ is computable, then $L$ is in fact computable. Given a string $x$ of length $n$, calculate $f(n)$, and then run a recognizer for $L$ on all strings of length $n$. Eventually you will find all $f(n)$ strings recognized by $L$. If $x$ is one of them, accept, and otherwise, reject.

Comment: When you say "then run a recognizer for L on all strings of length n" you mean in parallel for every string of length n?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.